# WWW::Mechanize: How To Click Button Based On Its Number in Form

Tags: html, forms, perl, www-mechanize

There is a button on a website at the end of a form that I cannot seem to click with WWW::Mechanize. Here is the bit of HTML pertaining to this button:

```
<input type="submit" class="saveButton" value="Login">
```

When I `print $mech->find_all_inputs();`, I get return this:

```
HTML::Form::TextInput=HASH(0x7f8f52cdc450)
HTML::Form::TextInput=HASH(0x7f8f5302b488)
HTML::Form::SubmitInput=HASH(0x7f8f52cdc108)
```

The third one is the one I want to click. I'm not exactly sure how to click this button even though I've found it. I tried `click(field(n => 3))`, I tried assigning a variable $submit to `find_all_inputs(3)`, then `click($submit);`, and no matter what, this button is not clicked.

Can anyone guide me as to how to click this elusive button?

> **Edit** (after question answered)

Interrogating the HTML form found I was actually entering the password for the login into the 'Forgot my Password' field of the form. Why this field was not coming up for `$mech->find_all_inputs()`, I don't know since "Login" was. Either way, clicking the button takes me to the next page. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that `click` works, however, I am not moving to the next page (the button in question is a login button, so clicking it should lead to another url, right? But '$ua -> uri;' is the same before and after clicking the button). I tried `my $response = $ua -> click();` and `print $response`, which returned `HTML::Form::SubmitInput=HASH(0x7f8f52cdc108)`, which is why I think `click` worked.

Comment: Does your Mechanize object have cookies?
consider doing
`my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( 
     cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies->new( file => "$ENV{HOME}/.cookies.txt" ) 
     );`
to get cookies. It seems highly unlikely you could login without.

Comment: @bytepusher: The `WWW::Mechanize` constructor by default behaves as if you had passed the option `cookie_jar => {}`, which creates an in-memory `HTTP::Cookies` object.

Comment: Pasting what @bytepusher recommends into my code returns: `Can't locate object method "new" via package "HTTP::Cookies" at test.pl line 10`. I'm not exactly sure why. The module HTTP::Cookies is up to date on my system.

Comment: Sorry, I faintly remembered having to pass one in. Guess I was wrong. Apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to select the appropriate form first, then call [`click`](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/WWW-Mechanize-1.78/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech-%3Eclick%28_$button_[,_$x,_$y]_%29)? It says (my emphasis)

> Has the effect of clicking a button on the **current form**.

Find which form on the page you need. Let's say it's form number 2.

```
# $ua is the User Agent (Mechanize object), at the appropriate page
$ua->form_number(2);
# fill the form ...
my $response = $ua->click();
```

or

```
$ua->submit_form( 
    form_number => 2, 
    # fields => { name => $value }  # can fill it here as well
};
```

I find `click` to be perhaps more reliable overall.

To inspect the forms you can use `my @forms = $ua->forms`. To fill the form you can use `select` or `set_fields`, for example. See [`Form Methods`](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/WWW-Mechanize-1.78/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#FORM_METHODS) and [`Field Methods`](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/WWW-Mechanize-1.78/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#FIELD_METHODS). All this operates with [`HTML::Form`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Form-6.03/lib/HTML/Form.pm) objects so you can use its methods as well. For example,  `value_names` and `possible_values` are handy.

If this doesn't help please give us more detail -- the web page in question would be ideal.

Comment: Click seems to have worked, but the action the click should have done hasn't. Inspecting the html, I see that when I roll over the line from my question, there is a  `= $0` at the end, like so: `<input type="submit" class="saveButton" value="Login"> = $0`. Maybe that helps? I haven't really worked with HTML in the past

Comment: @AdityaJ.  This new info does help a little.  First, deal with cookies per comment by [bytepusher](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4204037/bytepusher).  Next, is there more in that form with 'Login' button? How do you do that when you go to the page manually -- do you have other fields to fill out or is there just the 'Login' button?  Also, make sure to find out how many forms there are (by `$ua->forms`), so that you do `form_number` for the right one.  Finally, you are getting back the `HTML::Form` object -- you can interrogate that by its methods.  Or, unpack the hashref.

Comment: I am already able to fill the username and password fields, which are the only fields beside login in the form

Comment: And that is the only form on the page

Comment: @AdityaJ.  Good -- so did it all work in the end?  Thank you for the attribution.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is the first button in the form, you can write this

```
$mech->click_button( n => 1 )
```

or, since it's `value` attribute is `Login`, you can do this

```
$mech->click_button( value => 'Login' )
```

But since it is the only button in the form, just

```
$mech->click
```

should work fine